# Wp google maps pro checkboxes to behave like radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, checkbox

I'm having this problem with WP Google Maps Pro filters/categories. Basically the plugin offers to display the categories as select dropdown and checkboxes. And since the select dropdown proved not that much of an help I tried to implement the radio button functionality on the checkboxes.

So what I'm trying to do here is make these checkboxes behave like radio buttons. So when one is checked others become unchecked. There's a catch though. I have to make the click on the parent rather than on the child. The checkbox itself was requested by my client to be hid, since it breaks his design, and I have to make the functionality of the tab switching in order to filter the markers.

I've hidden the checkboxes with css, and I've styled the parent and added some icons with jquery. Below is the html layout.

```
<div class="parent">
   <i class="category-icon-one"></i>
   <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_4" 
name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="1" value="4" tabindex="0">
    First Category
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <i class="category-icon-two"></i>
   <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_4" 
name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="1" value="4" tabindex="0">
   Second Category
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery that I've managed to do so far:

```
$('.parent').click(function(){
  $('.parent').each(function(){
      $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  });
  $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
});
```

So far this has not proved fruitful, so I need to find a way to make this radio button like functionality while clicking on the parent of the checkboxes. I would appreciate if some light were to shine on this. Thanks :)

EDIT: The plugin makes the filtering of the markers through this piece of code. This where the checked states are being registered only as clicks, and the clicked value then is being used to filter the markers. Hope this helps to clarify my issue!

```
jQuery("body").on("click", ".wpgmza_checkbox", function() {
/* do nothing if user has enabled store locator */
   var wpgmza_map_id = jQuery(this).attr("mid");
   if (jQuery("#addressInput_"+wpgmza_map_id).length > 0) { } else {
      var checkedCatValues = jQuery('.wpgmza_checkbox:checked').map(function() {
                    return this.value;
                }).get();
                if (checkedCatValues[0] === "0" || typeof checkedCatValues === 'undefined' || checkedCatValues.length < 1) {
                    InitMap(wpgmza_map_id,'all');
                    wpgmza_filter_marker_lists(wpgmza_map_id,'all');
                } else {
                    InitMap(wpgmza_map_id,checkedCatValues);
                    wpgmza_filter_marker_lists(wpgmza_map_id,checkedCatValues);
                }
            }
 });
```

Comment: If the check-box is hidden anyway, why not just use the radio buttons instead? Or is that not possible with the plugin for some reason? As I understand the question you want to click on the parent of the input (radio or check-box) to select the descendant input and deselect others in the group of same name?

Comment: The plugin doesn't not offer the radio button functionality. I tried editing the  plugin's backend to make it with radio button but the code itself was a mess so I switched my focus on making a front-end solution.

Comment: @DavidThomas - So basically there are 10 categories. Each of them are inside a div with a class parent. So whenever I click in a div the checkbox inside it is checked. So when this happens I want all the other checkboxes to be unchecked.

Comment: Your code, as tested here: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sLzL6agk/), seems to work.

Comment: Hmm yeah, in the fiddle it does. However, in my project it only makes the functionality possible if a 'click' is registered. It's as if the 'checked' attribute is not being parsed. Is there anyway for me to trigger a click on one checkbox and at the same time uncheck the others? @DavidThomas

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem - or the explanation of the problem - can you reproduce the actual problem (with "*[MCVE]*" code) in a JS Fiddle? Once you've done that it would make sense to either delete this question and ask a new one focusing on the problems/differences you've identified in reproducing the problem, or profoundly editing this question  to focus on the newly identified problems.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Sorry if I've been misleading with my issue. I've given another edit to my question, hope it gives further explanations to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick from WP Google Maps here.

I'm a bit late to the party with this but I'll help where I can.

You can change the code to the following:

```
jQuery("body").on("click", ".wpgmza_checkbox", function() {
    var wpgmza_map_id = jQuery(this).attr("mid");
    var orig_element = jQuery(this);
    if (jQuery("#addressInput_"+wpgmza_map_id).length > 0) { } else {
        // get the value of the current checked checkbox
        var checked_value = jQuery(this).attr("value");
        if (checked_value === "0" || typeof checked_value === 'undefined' || checked_value.length < 1) {
            InitMap(wpgmza_map_id,'all');
            wpgmza_filter_marker_lists(wpgmza_map_id,'all');
        } else {
            InitMap(wpgmza_map_id,checked_value);
            wpgmza_filter_marker_lists(wpgmza_map_id,checked_value);
        }
        // reset all other checkboxes
        jQuery("input:checkbox[class^=wpgmza_checkbox]").each(function(i) {
          if (jQuery(orig_element).attr('value') !== jQuery(this).val()) { jQuery(this).attr('checked',false); }
        });
    }
});
```

I've tested this and it works.